# Upgraded TFS, Build/Test Controllers/Agents and VS to 2013, now CodedUI tests not executing due to missing 2012 assembly reference

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

We just upgraded from TFS/VS2012 to TFS/VS2013 and now no CodedUI tests can be executed as part of a build workflow.  I now get the following error when running any test as part of a build workflow:

> Error adding test case [<#>] to test run: Unable to load the test
>   container "\\.dll" or one of its dependencies. 
>   Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version =
>   11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Our setup is as follows:

**TFS Server:**

- Windows Server 2012 Standard
- TFS 2013 Update 2 (12.0.30324.0)
- Visual Studios is NOT installed

**Build Server (Used to create the build A):**

- Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
- TFS 2013 Update 2 (12.0.30324.0)
- Visual Studio Premium 2012 (11.0.50727.1)
- Visual Studio Premium 2013 (12.0.21005.1)
- Agents for Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.21005.1) (NOTE: These are not
  used for this build/deploy/test workflow)

**Build/Test Controller (Used to trigger build A on the above server, then execute the deploy/test workflow/build B):**

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- TFS 2013 Update 2 (12.0.30324.0
- Test Controller for VS2013 (12.0.21005.1)
- Visual Studio Premium 2013 (12.0.21005.1)
- Visual Studio Test Professional 2013 (12.0.21005.1)

**Test Agent:**

- Windows Server 2012 Standard
- Agents for Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.21005.1)

**Development Environment:**

- Windows Server 2012 Standard
- Visual Studio Premium 2013 (12.0.21005.1)
- Visual Studio Test Professional 2013 (12.0.21005.1)

In our environment, Build A is the build that creates the build/setup packages.  Build B is what deploys the build/setups to a lab environment and executes the tests.

- I can run the tests without issue from the dev environment, on the dev
  environment
- I cannot run the tests via mstest cmdline from the controller
- The DLL Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting exists at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies" on both the Test Controller and the Test Agent, but the version = 12.0.21005.1, not 11.0 which is what the error is complaining about
- If Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting version 12.0 is replaced with version 11.0 from another machine for troubleshooting purposes, the same error displays but for each of the following dll's:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

After replacing all of the above version 12.0 DLL's with version 11.0 DLL's, I then get the following error when firing off Build B:

> Failed to initialize the unit test extension 'urn:CodedUITest': A unit
>   test extension is not registered for the following attribute:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute

I've tried everything I could think of or find online to troubleshoot this issue, but I'm all out of ideas. Any suggestions on where to go from here to get my CodedUI tests running again?  In theory, TFS, Build Controller/Agent, Test Controller/Agent and VS are all upgraded to 2013, so why are 2012(version 11) dll's needed?

Comment: This has to do with the GAC, which I choose not to manage. I install TFS 2012 and 2013 on the TFS server, and furghet about it. Total cop out.